# Javascript/HTML Image Change

Tags: javascript, html, image

My task for my Javascript class is to create a script for this page that changes the image every 3 seconds. I think my code is correct, however Firebug tells me "document.getElementByID is not a function." Can someone show me what I am doing incorrectly?

This is my JS script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0
    var lightArray = ["pumpkinOff.gif", "pumpkinOn.gif"]
    var currentLight = document.getElementByID('light')
    // ChangeLight Method Prototype
    function changeLight() {
        currentLight.src = lightArray[i++];
        if (i == lightArray.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    setInterval(changeLight, 3000)
</script>
```

Here is my edited HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JavaScript for Programmers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Happy Halloween!</h2>
        <img id="pumpkin" src="pumpkinoff.gif" alt="pumpkin">
        <script src="../Script/spooky.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo it should be:

```
 var currentLight = document.getElementById('light'); //Not ID
```

Comment: oh my god, such a small detail that I've been pulling my hair out for hours. It works now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect capitalisation on

```
var currentLight = document.getElementByID('light')
```

Should be:

```
var currentLight = document.getElementById('pumpkin')
```

I have attached a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/11csf4k2/

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Id` not `ID`:

```
document.getElementById('light');
```

Also note that you don't have element with id `light` on your page. It probably should be

```
document.getElementById('pumpkin');
```

Comment: Such a small detail that ruined everything. Thanks dude, you saved me so much stress.